# Do SQL Server subqueries cause performance loss?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join, query-optimization

I connected 2 tables with inner join, but 2 tables have columns with the same name. I made my query a subquery to use only the required column. Will it cause a loss of speed if I use subquery?

Note : I used translate

```
Select
    *
From 
    (Select
         t1.Id, ...
     From
         Table1 as t1
     left join
         Table2 as t2 on t1.Id = t2.ParentId
     --Where
         --Id = 123 This Line. Error : Ambiguous column name 'Id'.
    ) as Foo
where
    Id = 123
```

Comment: Hmm, you obviously know how to uses aliases and qualify column identifiers, so why don't you just do that in the `WHERE` clause to resolve the ambiguity? To the question: Check the plan. But I think it is very likely that the optimizer pushes the `WHERE` clause down and there's no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a subquery. You resolve the ambiguity by prefixing the column with the table it belongs to:

```
select t1.Id, ...
from Table1 as t1
left join Table2 as t2 on t2.ParentId = t1.Id
where t1.Id = 123  -- presumably
```

As for your original query: does using a subquery here affects performance? I would expect a database such as SQL Server to foresee the obvious optimization of pushing the predicate to the subquery. But you would need to compare the execution plans to make sure.

Note that if you really need a subquery, it is usually better to pre-filter:

```
select t1.Id, ...
from (select * from Table1 where Id = 123) as t1
left join Table2 as t2 on t2.ParentId = t1.Id
```

Comment: I can't specify with the table alias for dynamic  condition

Comment: There's no Dynamic SQL in your question @A.CanD. , and even if there were, you can still alias objects in dynamic statements.

Answer (score 0):

In your Query the last line which holds the **where condition** give the *alias name* for the ID it will avoid the ambiguity error.